# Combobox to show items in ascending order

Tags: excel, vba

With the help of belwo coding, I am able to remove duplicate items from combobox but it is not reflecting items in ascending order. I want to reflect all the items in combobox in ascending order.
Please assist.

```
ComboBox37.Clear
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each rCell In wksSource.Range("M6", wksSource.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp))
            If Not .exists(rCell.Value) Then
                .Add rCell.Value, Nothing
            End If
    Next rCell
    ComboBox37.List = .keys
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

An `ArrayList` is another useful data structure for cases like this, which supports a `Contains` method (similar to the `Dictionary.Exists` method) and also a `Sort` method. This will be very useful especially if you don't want to manipulate (sort) the worksheet data itself:

```
Dim list As Object
Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set rng = wksSource.Range("M6", wksSource.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp))
ComboBox37.Clear
For Each rCell In rng.Cells
    If Not list.Contains(rCell.Value) Then list.Add (rCell.Value)
Next rCell
Dim v
'Sort the ArrayList object:
list.Sort
ComboBox37.list = list.ToArray()
Set list = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've got there is a good start, you just need to immediately sort them once they're all loaded:

```
ComboBox37.Clear
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each rCell In wksSource.Range("M6", wksSource.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp))
            If Not .exists(rCell.Value) Then
                .Add rCell.Value, Nothing
            End If
    Next rCell
    ComboBox37.List = .keys
End With

With ComboBox37
    For a = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        For b = a To .ListCount - 1
            If .List(b) < .List(a) Then
                c = .List(a)
                .List(a) = .List(b)
                .List(b) = c
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With
```